# Lock Focus inside a ListView on a TV Layout

Tags: android, listview, focus

I'm trying to find a way to lock the user inside a ListView (When using the D-Pad) preventing it from losing focus, allowing the user to navigate only through the ListView until "exit" is explicitly called.

There's any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found!

If you need this, it will be enough to set those parameters in xml:

```
android:id="@+id/myListView"
android:nextFocusDown="@id/myListView"
android:nextFocusForward="@id/myListView"
android:nextFocusLeft="@id/myListView"
android:nextFocusRight="@id/myListView"
android:nextFocusUp="@id/myListView"
```

Of course myListView is just an example id, and you could use this technique with any kind of View, it locks the focus setting the next focus to itself, in any direction.

The user is then locked inside that view until the view disappears or the focus is programmatically moved to another view.